# Can I print both side using gutenprint driver in canon ip2770?

Tags: printing, canon, duplex-printing

I am using ubuntu 20.04 version and canon ip2770 printer. I installed gutenprint driver for printing (ran `sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint` in terminal). I would do duplex printing (manual) when I was in windows but here I see no option of duplex printing in libreoffice or other places. So can I do duplex printing here?

Comment: If your printer hardware supports two sided printing, you can set it up by browsing `http://localhost:631/printers`.

Answer (score 0):

Print odd pages. Flip paper stack and return to feeder. Print even pages. That's about the best it gets for such an old printer.

Comment: Thanks. I saw this option as well. But I wanted to print partial portion of a document. Now I would split the document and do this as you said, but it's not gonna be a easy solution like windows. That's why I asked if I can find any way to duplex print partial portion of my document.